# Activity diagram UML: An alternative flow within an alternative flow?

Tags: uml, activity-diagram

Taken that there is another basic flow and carwash is already an alternative flow:

[image]

**A1 : Check cars to be washed**

A1.1  The system searches the car in the garage system whether it needs to be washed or not

A1.2  The system found the cars and gives the cars status = 'to wash'

> (When step A1.1 does not find the car, it should check the parking
> system before the status = 'to investigate') I describe this part in the Special requirements part of my Use Case template.

**A2 (or A1.1?): Check parkingspot system**

A2.1 The system checks the cars in the parking system with status 'to wash'

> So in this case A1 and A2 needs to be checked before it gets = 'to
> investigate'

**The struggle:**

I am struggling with the fact that my alternative flow 2 is on paper the process after step A1.1 of alternative flow 1 and it feels like it is an alternative flow of alternative flow 1 because it checks another system when it couldn't find data during step A1.1. Is it a problem to model it like this while there is also a step A1.2?
How can I model a process like that in an activity diagram? Or is it ok to model it as A1 and A2 (even when A2 is a process which take place after step A1.1 and there is also a step A1.2)?

Comment: what is the first element after "basic flow1" ? if a decision node what are the guards on the output flows ?

Comment: when you found the car on the decision node after A2 why do you check again going to A1 ? `A2.2 The system found the car and gives the car status = 'to wash'` : this is not what is done in your diagram

Comment: it seems you created  problem(s) from a wrong solution, rather than to try to solve artificial problem(s) you created what is the initial/real goal, just to sear a car in the garage and if not found in the parking  ?

Comment: Ahh a2.2 doesnt need to be there. I have removed it. Does it make sense now?

Comment: @bruno yes when it is not found in system 1 it should check system 2. Not found? Then change status. But when it is found during a1.1 then it can go to 1.2

Comment: as your previous question you mix single element and collection of elements, producing problems. You did not answer about first element after "basic flow 1"

Comment: again what is the goal ? how many cars can need to be wash at the same time ? if no car(s) to wash status investigate cannot be set on a car else which one ?

Comment: Hi Bruno. I want to say with this example that it is an existing usecase with basic flows and alternative flows. The activities(like check cars to be washed) exist of more subactivities. So A1 already exists and a2 doesnt. The overallpoint is that 1 car can be washed at a time and that two system needs to be checked (our own system and an external system) before it can go to status 'to investigate'. That is the goal. To find a specific car. Does not exist in our system? Then vheck the external system.

Comment: The preconditions: we know we had a car with number GJ35X for example and we want to find it, only we dont know whether it is in the garage system or in the parking spot system. It needs to go to investigate status when we can not find it in both systems. Reasons to not find both cars could be that the car has been sold

Comment: ok, so that manages just one car, this is not always the case in your diagram (*check car**s** to be washed*). I put an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from your last remark :

> The preconditions: we know we had a car with number GJ35X for example and we want to find it, only we dont know whether it is in the garage system or in the parking spot system. It needs to go to investigate status when we can not find it in both systems

the activity manages just one car and can be :

[image]